# CSV only returns strings. I need to keep value types

Tags: ruby, csv, spreadsheet, object-type

I'm trying to parse through a CSV file and grab every row and upload it to Postgres. The problem is that `CSV.foreach` returns every value as a string and Postgres won't accept string values in double columns.

Is there an easy way to keep the value types? Or am I going to have to go column by column and convert the strings into doubles and date formats?

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach("C:\\test\\file.csv") do |row|
    print row
end
```

All I need is the values to keep their type and not be returned as a string. I don't know if this is possible with CSV. I have it working just fine when using spreadsheet gem to parse through .xls files.

Comment: Use postgres `COPY` command.. Postgres will handle it..

Comment: I don't have superuser rights. I know there is a /copy command that doesn't require being a superuser but I'm not sure how to use it through ruby.

Comment: CSV *is* string data. If your data is normalized you can do things like attempt to convert to a numeric; if it works, it's a number, if it fails, it's a string.

Comment: It will fail. I need to change the strings to their correct type.

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL, I'd highly recommend using the [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) ORM. It'll make your life very easy. The documentation has many examples of inserting data.

Comment: Would you use sequel over the pg gem?

Comment: Yes. The pg gem is a a low-level interface to the Postgres client. Sequel is a high-level ORM which is much more full featured and will make it easy to move code from PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Sybase, and a good number of other DBMs with very little, to no, modification of your code. They're completely different concepts. We use Sequel in our production systems and did full migrations from MySQL to PGSQL with no recoding.

Answer (score 3):

CSVs do not natively have types; a CSV contains simple comma-separated text. When you view a CSV, you are seeing everything there is to the file. In an Excel file, there is a lot of hidden metadata that tracks the type of each cell.

When you `#foreach` through a CSV, each row is given as an array of string values. A row might look something like

```
[ "2.33", "4", "Hello" ]
```

with each value given as a string. You may think of "2.33" as a float/double, but CSV parsers only know to think of it as a string.

You can convert strings to other types using Ruby's type conversion functions, assuming each column contains only one type (which, since you're using an SQL database, is a pretty safe assumption).

You could write something like this, to convert the values in each row to specific types. This example converts the first row to a float (which should work with Postgres' `double), converts the second row to an integer, and the third row to a string.

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach("C:\\test\\file.csv") do |row|
    puts [ row[0].to_f, row[1].to_i, row[2].to_s ] 
end
```

Given the sample row from above, this function would print an array like

```
>> [ 2.33, 4, "Hello" ]
```

You should be able to use these converted values in whatever else you're doing with Postgres.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid this in case of files where there are 40 columns I need to selectively convert, but it seems like the only way.

Comment: The comment below actually answers the question better. If you want to edit your answer and include both I'll choose yours.

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach("test.txt", converters: :all) do |row|
    print row
end
```

This should convert numerics and datetimes. For integers and floats this works perfectly, but I was not able to get an actual conversion to DateTime going.